# What are "stripes" in relation to ancient Roman slaves?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome

I'm reading the Cambridge medieval history collection, specifically the chapter on Roman law (Justinian and earlier, vol2, ch3), and there is this [sentence](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.20410/page/65/mode/2up?q=stripes) pertaining to serfs:

> And for some offences, *e.g.* marrying a freewoman, he was liable by statute, like a slave, to chains or stripes.

In an aha! moment I thought I'd stumbled on to the origin of striped prison uniforms, but so far google says that came about much later. So what are these stripes? Is it a reference to being whipped? Was it something they actually wore?

Comment: As it is a punishment, perhaps the marks left by whipping (but I can't confirm that 100%).

Comment: I can't find that quote anywhere... history without sources is like physics without units; only useful when drunk.  The only reference I found to "stripes" in [Justinian's code](https://droitromain.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/Anglica/CJ1_Scott.htm) refers to construction of unauthorized worship facilities.

Comment: Seconding @LarsBosteen's comment: I have a dim impression that something like "to receive stripes" once-upon-a-time meant "to receive [whip] lashes"...

Comment: Very common in older British formal documents - whipping. See e.g. https://www.battlefields.org/learn/primary-sources/rules-regulating-army-observation-raised-colony

Answer (score 24):

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stripe#etymonline_v_22187):

> **stripe (n.2)**
>
> "a stroke or lash with a whip," c. 1400, probably a special use of **stripe (n.1)**, from the marks left by a lash. Compare also Dutch *strippen* "to whip," West Frisian *strips*, which apparently are cognate with the English word but are not attested so early. The notion might be the long, narrow, discolored mark on flesh from a stroke or lash.

Comment: The word 'strippen' in Dutch does **not** refer to marks left by a lash. That would be 'streep'.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not a mix-up you want to make. Could get awkward in social situations.

Comment: @Jos Was a common spelling of words that well established in 1400s Dutch manuscripts?

Comment: @Graham No, but that doesn't mean the word strippen means to whip. It comes much closer to 'to strip'. If it *sounds* the same that doesn't automatically the same meaning. Take for example 'bellen'. In Dutch it means to ring a bell or someone on the phone. In German it means to bark (like a dog). Meir should give a definition of the Middelnederlands word 'strippen' or a citation.

Comment: @Jos: Meir _has_ given a citation (from the Online Etymology Dictionary). The cited material may be _wrong_, but...

Comment: @Jos You could contact them at etymonline@protonmail.com with the correction.

Comment: No way for me to judge, but this gives it as "to whip" and also marks it as obsolete ( https://books.google.com/books?id=6Pm-TE5klx8C&pg=RA1-PA372#v=onepage&q&f=false ) 1749; published in amsterdam

Comment: FWIW, a relatively common reference is the Biblical quote used in Handel's Messiah, "By His Stripes, We Are Healed", referring to Jesus's scourging.

Comment: @Yorik That is an interesting find, but I remain skeptical. The usage of Dutch from its origins to today is exceptionally well documented across multiple voluminous dictionaries. About a decade ago these were digitized and since then have been accessible free of charge at the [Institute of the Dutch Language](https://ivdnt.org/woordenboeken/woordenboek-der-nederlandsche-taal/). I have been unable to find evidence for "strippen" = whip by searches of their entire database. It is possible but unlikely that I am using the search forms incorrectly

Answer (score 7):

"Stripes" is used throughout the bible as a synonym for whipping or beating, or the results thereof.

An often cited passage occurs in Isaiah 53:5, - seen here [in a number of translations](https://biblehub.com/isaiah/53-5.htm).

- "But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; **and with his stripes we are healed**."

[Here](https://biblescan.com/search.php?q=%2B%22stripes%22) are about 30 biblical uses in this context. (The few in Genesis 30, and Proverbs 7:16  do not relate).

The King James Bible was first published in 1604 and uses stripes in this context throughout.
This [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+stripes+we+are+healed%2CHis+stripes+we+are+healed&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) plot shows shows the prevalence of the Isaiah quote in English literature. This usage in the still much read KJV version has very likely contributed to the ongoing usage of the term.

[image]